# Joining data.table seems to be replacing values with NA's

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to join two data.tables the same way I would join data frames with merge() with all=TRUE, like so:

```
> x = data.frame(index = 1:10)
> y = data.frame(index = c(2,4,6), weight = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.5))
> x
   index
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      4
5      5
6      6
7      7
8      8
9      9
10    10
> y
  index weight
1     2    0.2
2     4    0.3
3     6    0.5
> merge(x,y, all=TRUE)
   index weight
1      1     NA
2      2    0.2
3      3     NA
4      4    0.3
5      5     NA
6      6    0.5
7      7     NA
8      8     NA
9      9     NA
10    10     NA
```

I have two data tables, matched.weights and casted, which was the result of a cast function. Their keys are both "index".

```
> matched.weights
      index
 [1,]     1
 [2,]     2
 [3,]     3
 [4,]     4
 [5,]     5
 [6,]     6
 [7,]     7
 [8,]     8
 [9,]     9
[10,]    10
First 10 rows of 14708 printed. 
> casted
      index            1            2
 [1,] 10002 0.0049024578 3.057794e-03
 [2,] 10129 0.0011064567 8.481497e-04
 [3,] 10171 0.0012964050 5.540875e-03
 [4,] 10177 0.0008181397 6.981567e-04
 [5,] 10187 0.0060350971 2.156695e-03
 [6,]  1022 0.0011320117 8.665125e-04
 [7,] 10250 0.0047892924 7.725221e-03
 [8,] 10262 0.0044724898 8.787161e-06
 [9,] 10286 0.0016650838 7.162887e-05
[10,] 10299 0.0015840791 5.578903e-03
First 10 rows of 305 printed.
```

I get this error when I try to merge them:

```
> merge(matched.weights, casted, all=TRUE)
Error in setcolorder(dt, c(setdiff(names(dt), end), end)) : 
  neworder is length 5 but x has 3 columns.
```

And when I use the data.table syntax it replaces the data entries with NA's:

```
> merged = casted[matched.weights]
> merged
      index X1 X2
 [1,]     1 NA NA
 [2,]     2 NA NA
 [3,]     3 NA NA
 [4,]     4 NA NA
 [5,]     5 NA NA
 [6,]     6 NA NA
 [7,]     7 NA NA
 [8,]     8 NA NA
 [9,]     9 NA NA
[10,]    10 NA NA
First 10 rows of 14708 printed. 
> merged[10002]
     index X1 X2
[1,] 10002 NA NA
> sum(merged[[2]], na.rm=T)
[1] 0
```

Can anyone explain to me what is going on?

Comment: This is expected behaviour. You should use `merge` instead.

Comment: @Andrie But OP got an error with `merge`.

Comment: I think we read the question differently. I'll post an answer.

Comment: @user1465472 Please remember to state which version of `data.table` you're using when asking for help. It really helps to avoid solved issues. The error from `setcolorder` looks like a known and fixed bug.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have the most recent version. I got it through `install.packages("data.table")` a week ago.

Comment: That'll be v1.8.0 then. The intention (with all R software) is that when you get an error message, search and check NEWS first. See link to up to the minute news at the top of `?data.table`. There is indeed a bug fix that mentions `setcolorder` in 1.8.1. As it happens, 1.8.1 was submitted to CRAN as 1.8.2 last night. In this case, at this time, I'd suggest upgrading to 1.8.3 on the R-Forge repository and see if that fixes the error. Follow the link from the homepage to R-Forge and copy and paste the `install.packages` command with the `repos` argument. Or maybe Andrie's answer solves it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to `merge` two data tables (in the sense of a full outer join, similar to `all=TRUE`) you need to use `merge.data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dtx <- data.table(x, key="index")
dty <- data.table(y, key="index")
merge(dtx,dty, all=TRUE)
   index weight
1      1     NA
2      2    0.2
3      3     NA
4      4    0.3
5      5     NA
6      6    0.5
7      7     NA
8      8     NA
9      9     NA
10    10     NA
```

This is the same result you get as when using a data frame (but it is much faster).

It's worth noting that some of the `merge` functionality was improved in recent versions of `data.table`, so be sure to get the latest stable version.  I am using version 1.8.0.